# 3 digit number is a unique number if no digit is repeating

Tags: combinatorics

A 3 digit number is a unique number if no digit is repeating. In how many ways 3 unique numbers can be chosen such that they do not have any digit in common?

Comment: How many choices do you have for the first digit? Now, fix the first digit and ask how many choices you have left for the second digit, etc.

Comment: 3 unique numbers, means 9 digits in total, and they have to be different, so use @muffle's suggestion and it will be done

Comment: @freak_warrior: I would guess that for example that $(123,456,789)$ could be considered the same choice as $(456,789,123)$, so you need a bit more. Anyway, the OP should clarify, and also show some work, so I'm voting to put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It doesn’t hurt to see more than one way to do things, so here’s a slightly different approach from the one suggested in the comments. Any set of three different three-digit numbers can be uniquely presented as a list in increasing order. For instance, if you chose the numbers $392,157$, and $684$, the list would be $\langle 157,392,684\rangle$. You want to count the lists of that kind.

Let $\langle a_1a_2a_3,b_1b_2b_3,c_1c_2c_3\rangle$ be a typical list, where the $a_k,b_k$, and $c_k$ are distinct digits.

- First choose the increasing list $\langle a_1,b_1,c_1\rangle$ of first digits; in how many ways can you do this? HINT: How many ways are there to pick a set of $3$ distinct first digits? Once you’ve picked them, there’s only one way to list them in increasing order.
- Now choose $a_2,a_3,b_2,b_3,c_2$, and $c_3$ in order; in how many ways can you do that?